# Counterfactual inference using functional causal model (Example from Koller-Friedman)

Tags: probability, distributions, causality

I'm currently studying Chapter 21 Causality from the book [Probabilistic Graphical Models (Koller, Friedman)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models). I'm struggling to understand how the values in the *joint posterior* have been obtained in the [Example 21.23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7H9S.png). The example builds on the situation presented in [Example 21.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXFTz.png). I hope it's ok for me to report screenshots of the examples in question.

Given the graph in Figure 21.5 (Example 21.8) we are interested in the query

$P(O'=o^1 \mid A=a^1, T=t^0, O=o^1, do(T'=t^1))$

My understanding is that the joint posterior is obtained by considering the observations that

$A=a^1, T=t^0$ and $O=o^1$,

which means that the only acceptable values for the response variables are

$U^T =$ "defier" or "never taker"

$U^O =$ "helped" or "never well"

Yet, I'm not sure how to condition the previous joint distribution in order to obtain the posterior in Example 21.23.